# Does $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}\{e^x\}dx=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: limits, summation, improper-integrals, fractional-part

This summation is as far as I got with $L=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\frac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a}\{e^x\}dx$:

$$L=\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{a}\left(1-n\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right)}{\ln a}$$

I don't know how to progress from here.

Comment: You can continue for example using a Taylor expansion: $1-n\log(1+1/n) = 1/(2n) + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$. Or you can simplify the summand first using $1 - n\log((n+1)/n)) = 1 + \log(n+1) - (n+1)\log(n+1) + n\log(n)$ (the two last terms telescopes).

Comment: @Winther Your second method is amazing. I think you should edit it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that by $\{x\}$ you mean the fractional part of $x$.  First observe that the limit does exist since $$\int_{-\infty}^{a} \{e^x\} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^x dx + \int_0^{a} \{e^x\} dx \le 1 + a $$
and therefore $\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{a} \{e^x\} dx \le 1+\frac{1}{a}$ for all $a>0$. Thus, $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\int_{-\infty}^{\log(n+1)} \{e^x\}dx$ and the integral can be simplified as
$$ \begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\log(n+1)} \{e^x\}dx &= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\log(k)}^{\log(k+1)} (e^x - k) dx = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left. (e^x - kx) \right|_{\log(k)}^{\log(k+1)} \\
&= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1-k\log(1+1/k)) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\end{align*}  $$
We have, $$\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\int_{-\infty}^{\log(n+1)} \{e^x\}dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(n)}{\log{(n+1)}} +O\left(\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\right) \to \frac{1}{2} $$